# Kotlin Map<String, List<Object>> compare to another Map<String, List<Object>>

Tags: android, list, kotlin, maps

```
Hi Awesome developers, I recently attended one interview and there was this question.
Can anyone answer this question and provide steps to solve it.
```

Question:
Let's consider something a user spends money on a "payee".
You are given [Map] of users and a list of payees the user has made payments to....
EG:

```
mostFrequentPayees: Map<String, List<String>> = {
"Bob": [ "Bell Canada", "Tim Hortons", "Amazon" ],
"Alex": [ "Starbucks", "Netflix", "Tim Hortons" ]
}
```

You are given a list of categories and the payees associated with them.....
EG:

```
categoryOfPayees: Map<String, List<String>> = {
"Phone": [ "Bell Canada" ],
"TV": [ "Bell Canada", "Netflix" ],
"Entertainment": [ "Bell Canada", "Netflix", "Amazon" ],
"Beverages": [ "Tim Hortons", "Starbucks" ],
"Fast Food": [ "Tim Hortons", "Starbucks" ],
}
```

Your job is to return a [Map] (of type Map<String, List>) of the most     frequent categories that the user spends money on....
EG:

```
Output = {
"Bob": [ "Entertainment" ],
"Alex": [ "Beverages", "Fast Food" ]
}




fun findMostFrequentCategories(
        mostFrequentPayees: Map<String, List<String>>,
        categoryOfPayees: Map<String, List<String>>
        ): Map<String, List<String>> {
    //TO DO
    return mapOf<String, List<String>>()
}

fun main() {

    val mostFrequentPayees: Map<String, List<String>> =
        mapOf(
            "Bob" to listOf("Bell Canada", "Tim Hortons", "Amazon"),
            "Alex" to listOf("Starbucks", "Netflix", "Tim Hortons")
        )

    val categoryOfPayees: Map<String, List<String>> =
        mapOf(
            "Phone" to listOf("Bell Canada"),
            "TV" to listOf("Bell Canada", "Netflix"),
            "Entertainment" to listOf("Bell Canada", "Netflix", "Amazon"),
            "Beverages" to listOf("Tim Hortons", "Starbucks"),
            "Fast Food" to listOf("Tim Hortons", "Starbucks")
        )

    val expectedResult: Map<String, List<String>> =
        mapOf(
            "Bob" to listOf("Entertainment"),
            "Alex" to listOf("Beverages", "Fast food")
        )

    println("Expected Result:\n$expectedResult")
    println("Actual Result:\n${findMostFrequentCategories(mostFrequentPayees,     categoryOfPayees)}")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `categoryOfPayees` is a map where:

- **Key** is a category.
- **Value** is a list of payees that fit in that category.

But this is backwards from what you need. You need a way to look up a category using a payee, so what you need is a map where:

- **Key** is a payee.
- **Value** is the category for that payee.

With no lists to deal with. Convert the original map into a new map where every payee is a key, and the value for each key is its payee. Now you have an easy category look-up map.

The `buildMap` higher order function provides a concise way to create a map (you don't have to create the map, put it in a variable, and keep referencing it). Here, we iterate through all of the payees from each value of the original map to add it as a key in the new map.

```
val categoriesByPayee = buildMap<String, String> {
    for ((category, payees) in categoryOfPayees) {
        for (payee in payees) {
            put(payee, category)
        }
    }
}
```

You can change the parameter in your function to use this simpler map. For each entry, you need to map the list from payees to categories of payee:

```
fun findMostFrequentCategories(
    mostFrequentPayeesByUser: Map<String, List<String>>,
    categoriesByPayee: Map<String, String>
): Map<String, List<String>> {
    return mostFrequentPayeesByUser.mapValues { (_, payees) ->
        payees.map { categoriesByPayee[it] }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the approach? Also, for the first part you mentioned Convert Category List into Map- It's already defined as a Map that its containing List within.

Comment: I expanded my explanation and I think it addresses your second sentence.